# What is preliminary work in a biological investigation?

Tags: experimental-design

Here is an example of preliminary work that confuses me (from an A level Biology exam question). Please help me by providing an explanation of preliminary work in the generic sense, then use the example below.

> A company is in the process of developing a new stain-removing washing liquid.
>   They want to include a protease enzyme to digest the proteins that are responsible for some stains on clothes. Plan an investigation to discover the optimum concentration of protease to use in this new stain-removing washing liquid.'

Here are the answers suggested as the preliminary work:

> 1. see if proposed method will work / will provide
>      measurable results
> 2. to check for suitable conditions for digestion
>      e.g. temperature, pH
> 3. select timescale (for measuring stain digestion)
> 4. idea of selecting a range of protease concentrations
> 5. check if the type of {protein / stain} is affected
> 6. select suitable dependent variable for measuring {digestion / removal / eq} of the {stain / protein/ eq }

Now, in my process of understanding what preliminary work is, I want to
question is there any other preliminary work that could be done on this investigation? Seems like there is a lot more to prepare for such an investigation. For example, at first sight, I suggested that secondary research needs to be carried out in order to identify the mean amount of stain and its distribution around that mean. Then that will be the suitable substrate concentration to be used. I also mentioned researching the type of proteases that the company wanted to use, alongside carrying out the preparation of the range of concentrations of enzymes that need to be used.